# How to specify API request header value in RAML

Tags: raml

Using RAML 1.0, I'd like to specify the *value* that a request header should have. The specification seems to only mention *properties* of the header

```
/foo-resources:
  post:
    description: Creates a foo
    headers:
      Connection: close  # define that connection header should have close value
    body:
      #...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No answers so have cross posted to RAML forum https://forum.raml.org/t/how-to-specify-api-request-header-value-in-raml/2553