# RAML, specify API request Content-Length value

Tags: api, mulesoft, raml

I'm trying to set the value of the Content-Length property to 0 in my RAML file.
I first stumbled upon this thread : [How to specify API request header value in RAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891578/how-to-specify-api-request-header-value-in-raml)

When I tried implementing it with this code :

```
/update:
  post:
    description: Store updated data in database
    headers:
      Content-Length:
        enum: [0]
    body:
      ...
```

I got the response 400 Bad Request :

```
   {
  "code": "REQUEST_VALIDATION_ERROR",
  "message": "Required header Content-Length is missing."
  }
```

My IDE told me a string was expected but feeding with ["0"] didn't solve the problem.
(I'm testing my API specification in Mulesoft Design Center.)

So is there something I did wrong or is there another way to set the Content-Length to 0 in the request's header ?

Comment: why are you trying to send a POST with zero length (ie no body)?

Comment: The client does not need to provide data through the body because the data is being retrieved through some external API's call. But in the end I am inserting the retrieved data in the database. As the call is modifying my db, I don't want to use GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only try to define custom headers in RAML. A required header of the HTTP protocol like Content-Length must not be defined. It should be automatically generated to prevent errors.

Comment: I read somewhere that the POST request with empty body could be denied by some proxies if a content-length of 0 is not specified. Is that untrue ?

Comment: It is kind of required but it is complex. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14759645/721855. Just let the tool generate it based on the body, and send the body empty. RAML doesn't have a good way to model empty bodies as far as I know.